# Json response for Nodejs with webMathematica

Tags: webmathematica, json-format

I am trying to pass RESTful calls from my Nodejs server application to webMathematica. How to do so? I also want to receive the response as JSON.

Comment: Welcome! Showing what code you already got in place is usually very useful. Please add as much detail and information as possible to facilitate answering.

Comment: you might find some information on using RESTful applications with Mathematica in this Q&A http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40731/graph-databases-nosql-with-mathematica/40822#40822