# How to create tickets on a Jira server using Mathematica?

Tags: code-request, webservices

Has anyone ever tried to use [Atlassian's rest api](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-create-issue)  from Mathematica? I'd love an example of a post request to create a ticket with specific properties.

With cURL, it's easy:

```
curl -D- -u [username] -p -X POST --data @[pathToJson] -H \"Content\
Type: application/json\" https://[YourCompany].atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/
```

But I'm not sure how to do it with URLFetch.

Comment: After scanning your link it looks like it should be straight forward using `URLFetch`. You would have to use your JSON data in the `"Body"` option. What have you tried so far? (related REST API usage examples: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40731/graph-databases-nosql-with-mathematica)

Comment: You can create the JSON data as nested lists of rules and then use `ExportString` to convert to JSON then add that to `URLFetch`. I don't have access to a JIRA to try but can write a conceptual answer for you to try if you like. I'll be away for 4-5 hours but when I get back

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Using the first example in the link to the JIRA API.

create your data in Mathematica:

```
data = {"fields" -> {
    "project" -> {"key" -> "TEST"},
    "summary" -> "REST ye merry gentlemen.", 
    "description" -> 
     "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names
using the REST API", "issuetype" -> {"name" -> "Bug"}
    }
  }
```

convert the Mathematica data to JSON:

```
jsondata = ExportString[data, "JSON"]

(* {
    "fields": {
        "project": {
            "key": "TEST"
        },
        "summary": "REST ye merry gentlemen.",
        "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
        "issuetype": {
            "name": "Bug"
        }
    }
} *)
```

Now post the data to the URL:

```
URLFetch["http://localhost:8090/rest/api/2/issue/",
 "Method" -> "POST",
 "Headers" -> {"Content-Type" -> "application/json"},
 "Username" -> "fred",
 "Password" -> "fred",
 "Body" -> jsondata
 ]
```

Comment: Authentication works, and I set my project key correctly, but I'm getting this error message: "{\"errorMessages\":[],\"errors\":{\"summary\":\"Field 'summary' \
cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or \
unknown.\",\"description\":\"Field 'description' cannot be set. It is \
not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.\"}}"

Comment: I looked this up in a jira forum, they say:
"The HTTP Basic Session Cookie just need to be preemptive:
httpRequest.addHeader(new BasicScheme().authenticate(new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username","password"), httpRequest));
Jira says its a JSON format problem, but it is a auth-error. Hope it helps other people."

Comment: @M.R. did you run the example in the answer or did you sub your own data in? It looks like the later and if that is the case you may be using fields that are not spelled correctly or do not exist. Can you confirm that the API examples work?

Comment: @M.R. you can use cookies with `URLFetch`. see the docs examples.

Comment: I ran the same data only switching the key, everything else works with curl the fields "summary", "description", "issuetype" are all standard and work when I use the @[json file path] in the curl command. Doing a RunProcess@StringSplit on the curl command string works, it's an issue with URLFetch, and I don't know how to use the cookies option here either.

Comment: Actually scratch that, doing a RunProcess@StringSplit on the curl command string doesn't work either, I get an <|"ExitCode" -> 0, 
 "StandardOutput" -> "HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type"...|>

Comment: Only guess but looks like a problem with your JSON. Why not run the example without any changes (other than username and password)? Also it is more useful to use `ReadList` or `Import` than `RunProcess` if you want to go down that path.

Comment: I think it's a problem with how Mathematica imports the Json, because the exact same Json file works with curl when references by file path. any other ideas?

Comment: In my answer there is no JSON file. Why not just try and test my answer with your username and password before trying other things? I have not encountered any problems with `ExportString` to JSON and have been using this with REST APIs for years. Since I do not have JIRA and do not know what you are doing there is nothing more I can suggest