# Mathematica with MongoDB database

Tags: databases

I try connect mathematica with my database NOSQL mongoDB but I have problem with create collection. I have Mathematica 10.2 and I download driver .net version 2.2 from this website [a link](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/)! I unpacking driver to :

```
    input : FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Links", "NETLink"}]
output : "C:\\Mathematica\\SystemFiles\\Links\\NETLink"
```

After unpacking zip folder to "C:\Mathematica\SystemFiles\Links\NETLink"
I install this pack and I connect to database and try createCollection but i have problem this is my code with output:

```
    In[2]:= InstallNET[] 
    Out[2]= LinkObject["C:\\Mathematica\\SystemFiles\\Links\\NETLink\\\InstallableNET.exe", 127, 4]
    In[13]:= conn = ConnectToMongoDB["localhost"]
    Out[13]= NETLink`Objects`NETObject$377462395502593
    In[5]:= GetMongoServer[conn_] := Module[{}, conn@GetServer[]]
    In[6]:= createCollection[conn_, db_String, collectionname_String] := Module[{server, database},
    server = GetMongoServer[conn];
    database = server@GetDatabase[db];
    database@CreateCollection[collectionname]
    ]
    In[8]:= createCollection[conn, "mydb", "test"]
    During evaluation of In[8]:=
    NET::nomethod: No public instance method named GetServer exists for the .NET type MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.
    Out[8]= $Failed[GetDatabase["mydb"]][CreateCollection["test"]]
```

I use MongoDB on Windows and I switch to mydb

```
    > use mydb
switched to db mydb
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong maybe some suggestions?

---

I must use only mathematica because I write engineering work about database connections and I must to use java or .Net. Thank you for this link b.gatessucks but when I use database link in java I have problem this problem:

```
    In[1]:= << MongoDBLink`
In[4]:= conn = OpenConnection[];
In[5]:= DatabaseNames[conn]
Out[5]= {"local"}
In[18]:= db = GetDatabase[conn, "local"]
In[19]:= CollectionNames[db]
Out[19]= {"name", "startup_log"}
In[20]:= coll = GetCollection[db, "name"]
In[21]:= InsertDocument[coll, {"a" -> #, "b" -> 2 #}] & /@ Range[5]
Out[21]= {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
In[23]:= FindDocuments[coll]


  During evaluation of In[23]:= Java::excptn: A Java exception occurred: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: MongoDBLinkUtils : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source).
During evaluation of In[23]:= LoadJavaClass::fail: Java failed to load class MongoDBLinkUtils. >>
Out[23]= MongoDBLinkUtils`Iterate[JLink`Objects`vm1`\
JavaObject11819681379778561]
```

Comment: Maybe useful [link](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/88662?_19_redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fcommunity.wolfram.com%2Fdashboard%3Fp_p_id%3D3%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dmaximized%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26_3_groupId%3D0%26_3_keywords%3Dmongo%26_3_struts_action%3D%252Fsearch%252Fsearch%26_3_redirect%3D%252Fweb%252Fcommunity%252Fdashboard%26_3_y%3D6%26_3_x%3D5).

Comment: the problem doesn't appear to be creating the collection but the function `GetServer[]`. Have you read the driver docs?

Comment: yes and i watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oU3y-kiFYLs this video and she had used this function. We can see this in 5:23 min.

Comment: okay next question then is whether there are some driver dependencies. Also do you need to use .NET?

Comment: If you do not need to use .NET then you may find it easier in the first instance to run mongo from within Mathematica via the terminal

Comment: Thank you for a help me with mongoDB but I still have a problem with connection I use your link github.com/zbjornson/MongoDBLink step by step for the instruction and I have problem when I use FindDocuments[coll] my problem I described in question Than you for every suggestion.

Comment: @bartek Try reinstalling the MongoDBLink package (repeat the instructions in the readme and restart the kernel). I had compiled it for java 1.8 and you're using an earlier version, which I have now compiled for.

Comment: @ZachB I have Java 1.8 and had the same issue

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch please open an issue on the github page if you want to go through troubleshooting -- not enough space here. Happy to help there.

Comment: @ZachB I just tried your latest download and had no problems. I already had Java 1.8.0_66 installed so not sure why compatibility with earlier versions was required for me but in any case it works now. Thanks!

Comment: Just an update: MongoDB support is coming in Wolfram Language version 11.3.

Answer (score 10):

Wolfram Language version 11.3 now has [support for MongoDB](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/MongoLink/guide/MongoLinkOperations.html).

You can connect to a MongoDB database via `MongoConnect`. For example, connecting to a database running locally:

```
In[1]:= Needs["MongoLink`"]
client = MongoConnect[];
MongoGetDatabaseNames[client]

Out[2]= {"Test", "admin"}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to bypass .NET and do something that I personally find more intuitive then run it all through the terminal. I'm running OS X 10.10 and have Mongo 3.2 installed. Create a document:

```
json = ExportString[{"old mcdonald" -> {"pig" -> 2, "cow" -> 4}}, "JSON"]

"{
    \"old mcdonald\": {
        \"pig\": 2,
        \"cow\": 4
    }
}"
```

Then add that document to your collection. Note that you do not have to create the collection ("farm") to begin with, it is automatically created. Ditto the database, called "example" in the code below:

```
ReadList["!/usr/local/mongodb/bin/mongo example --eval 'db.farm.insert(" <> json <> ")'", String]

(* {"MongoDB shell version: 3.2.0", "connecting to: example", "WriteResult({ \"nInserted\" : 1 })"} *)
```

Now go to your Mongo shell and verify the new collection:

[image]

I find this far less clunky than using the Java driver and associated functions (same applies to .NET)